# consulta pelo número do dia da semana Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A semana tem 7 dias, então quero poder fazer uma consulta que o utilizador consoante o dia da semana que escolher apresente o resultado:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_eventos WHERE WEEK(data) = '$semana_atual' AND YEAR(data) = '$ano_atual'");
```

Agora nesta consulta, quero tentar encaixar o dia da semana (`$dia_semana`) que vai de 1 a 7 e assim são apresentados todos os eventos daquele dia da semana, da semana e ano atual.

Ou seja, se escolher o dia da semana 4, ele vai listar os eventos do dia da semana 4, que corresponde a Quarta-feita.

Comment: A sua dúvida é em relação à consulta SQL ou à interface do usuário para escolher o dia da semana?

Answer (score 1):

Use a função `DAYOFWEEK` na coluna `data`. Ela retorna o índice do dia da semana, sendo que 1 é domingo, 2 é segunda e daí em diante.

Fonte: [documentação do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

Comment: Não é isso que procuro. Quero fazer a consulta a partir do dia da semana e não o contrário. Vamos imaginar que quero ir buscar o dia da semana 4, ele vai à BD buscar todos os eventos do dia da semana 4

Comment: SELECT * WHERE DAYOFWEEK(sua_data) = 4. Isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo, é só colocar na condição `WHERE`.